# How to deploy java selenium code in to azure instance?

Tags: java, azure, selenium

I have developed a web application in Spring boot, which has Selenium code to get few information's from websites. It's working fine as expected in local. When i deploy the same war file in to Azure i am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mylearning]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

Build info:

- version: '3.141.59',
- revision: 'e82be7d358',
- time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

System info:

- host: 'RD0050F2B60BD5',
- ip: '10.140.36.12',
- os.name: 'Windows Server 2016',
- os.arch: 'amd64',
- os.version: '10.0',
  java.version: '11.0.12'

Driver info:

- driver.version: ChromeDriver

It seems like the code is expecting chrome browser to be installed in azure. But we don't have an option to install chrome in azure. Can anyone please suggest a feasible way to execute selenium code in azure?